# When are the scenarios where 'tabs.onUpdated' event fired other that url changed

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, web-extension

In our extension code I have a listerner added to tabs.onUpdated ( chrome.tabs.onUpdated )

```js
  browser.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(async (tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
 
    }
  })
```

In one of the interactions inside extension on button click this event is fired due to changeInfo.status going to --> 'loading'  --> 'complete'

What could have possibly happend that status went to loading state ?
There is no change in url and this is leading to unecessary call to added listener

Comment: The tab is reloaded so the URL is the same.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for answering
This reload happend from common code ( web and extension) inside extension iframe and reload is not visible 
What kind of reload is this in client side code ?

Comment: Maybe they add an iframe. Use devtools in the tab to investigate what happens.